# Не удается обновить инвентарь покупок, после потери интернет соединения

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases, android-billing

В момент покупки товара теряется интернет соединение и в окне google play появляется уведомление "Нет подключения к интернету", после повторного подключения сети не приходит подтверждение об оплате (но деньги списываются и на почту приходит квитанция).
Смотрел на дебаге:

> Can't start async operation (refresh inventory) because another async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress

Получается что не удается получить инвентарь покупок, чтобы сделать consume, из-за того что не завершился процесс покупки.
Как можно решить эту проблемку?